# Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id' (Database first)

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

**Database-first solution.**

I'm using two tables called `User` and `Profile`. They are both using `uniqueidentifier` (SQL Server) as their primary key. The way I let `User` to automatically receive it's own guid id was from:

1. Open my edmx file.
2. Right click the Guid column for User -> Properties -> change the StoreGeneratedPattern to Identity.

Worked like a charm. Now I tried to do same with `Review`, but I'm getting the following error every time I'm trying to create a new row:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table
>   'xxxx.dbo.Profile'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The
>   statement has been terminated.

If I don't use `Identity` for `StoreGeneratedPattern` for `Profile`, it will not generate a unique ID, instead just bunch of zeros which lead to duplicated error if I try to create a new row again.

Why is User working fine but not `Profile`?

I followed this guide [guide](http://www.developerhandbook.com/entity-framework/entity-framework-use-a-guid-as-the-primary-key/) for both tables.

Comment: Your error message references a table named "Profil", not "Profile".  Is it possible you misspelled/named the table or class that it references?

Comment: You CANNOT use DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity for uniqueidentifier (Guid) columns. Guid columns in DBMS will never be autoincrement, and since you changed StoreGeneratedPattern to Identity, EF won't pass it as a value either, since it expects it to be given by DBMS.

Comment: in order to have it work, change StoreGeneratedPattern to None and set valid Guid values, or change the datatype.

Comment: @JimMcKeon Unfortunately I misspelled it in this post. Corrected it now.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro How do I set valid Guid values? I barely have any experience with Guid. EDIT: How come User table could get unique Guid values every time?

Comment: `How do I set valid Guid values` -> `modelInstance.GuidIdProperty = System.Guid.NewGuid();`

Comment: @igor Where do I put that code?

Comment: @DevilSuichiro Sure you can use `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity`. Skylake, I think the database table `Profile` doesn't have the default (`DEFAULT newsequentialid()`)

Comment: Do not add "Solved" in the question. Either add an answer explained how you solved it so its useful to others, or delete the question.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Aah.. Will do, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As @Gert Arnold mentioned in comments, I forgot to add `newsequentialid()` for `Profile`table in SQL Server. Once I did that,  I were finally able to generate unique Guids with `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity`.

You can read more about this method [here](http://www.developerhandbook.com/entity-framework/entity-framework-use-a-guid-as-the-primary-key/). This also include techniques for Code-First.